# Passing a function inside another function

Tags: javascript, function

When the user opens the page it's prompted for a number to generate a grid with this function

```
//CREATE GRID
function grid (size) {
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            const square = document.createElement("div");
            square.classList.add("square");
            square.style = "background-color: white; border: 1px solid black";
            container.appendChild(square);
        }
    }

}
size = prompt("How many squares wide do you want your grid to be?");
grid(size);
```

I have a button that allows the user to generate a new grid, and I want to pass the function above into a new function like this

```
//CUSTOM GRID
function custom() {
    generate.addEventListener("click", grid);
}
custom();
```

but it doesn't work. I guess I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `custom()` like this:

```
function custom() {
  generate.addEventListener("click", function(){
    size = prompt("How many squares wide do you want your grid to be?");
    grid(size);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `grid()` function takes as parameter a number named `size`.

[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) takes as parameter a function to which it passes an `Event`.

Therefore, `addEventListener("click", grid)` will call your `grid()` function with an `Event` as the first parameter, not a number as you expect.

You will need to obtain the `size` and pass it to the `grid()` call:

```js
addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Obtain size from somewhere. Maybe with the same prompt() as before,
    // or maybe from an <input> on the page, or some other way.
    const size = ...;

    // Now that you have the size, call grid() with it.
    grid(size);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to place the size initialization inside the `grid()` function:

```js
function grid () {
    const size = prompt("How many squares wide do you want your grid to be?");

    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            const square = document.createElement("div");
            square.classList.add("square");
            square.style = "background-color: white; border: 1px solid black";
            container.appendChild(square);
        }
    }

}

function custom() {
    generate.addEventListener("click", grid);
}
custom();
```